# Как считать информацию из текстового файла с помощью nasm на Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, x86, nasm, x86-64

Учу nasm на ОС Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). Получилось выести строку в терминал: вот код:

```
  section .data

  msg: db "Linux rules 4ever",0x0A,0
  msglen equ $-msg
  global _start

  _start:

  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, msg
  mov edx, msglen
  int 0x80

  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80
```

Компилирую командами:

```
    nasm -f elf File.asm -o prog01.o
    ld -m elf_i386 prog01.o -o prog01
```

Строка выводится в терминал. Теперь хочу усложнить задачу и вывести строку из файла .txt. Файл создал заранее через текстовый редактор nano в той же папке, где и файл .asm, вот код:

```
section .data

file: db "test.txt", 0
O_RDONLY equ 0
O_WRONLY equ 1
O_RDWR equ 2

O_CREATE equ 100o
O_TRUNC equ 1000o
O_APPEND equ 2000o 

section .bss

descriptor resb 4
buffer resb 20

section .text
global _start

_start:
mov eax, 5
mov ebx, file
mov ecx, O_RDWR
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

mov [descriptor],eax

 mov eax, 3
 mov ebx, [descriptor]
 mov ecx, [buffer]
 mov edx, 20

 int 80h ; Считали информацию из файла

 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, [buffer]
 mov ebx, 20

 int 0x80 ; "Записали" на экран

 mov eax,6

 mov ebx,[descriptor]

 int 0x80 ;закрытие файла

; выход из программы
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

Компилирую теми же командами только в файл prog02.o и prog02. Ошибок не выдает, но когда запускаю исполняемый файл, вывода текста не происходит, а терминал просто переводит каретку на новую строку. Помогите правильно считать иформацию из файла и вывести ее на экран.

Comment: @AlexF в он есть в nasm? Как его запустить?

Comment: Странное это занятие — программировать под юниксами на ассемблере. Юникс предполагает переносимость, ассемблер — полное отсутствие переносимости.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, а в целях обучения?

Comment: @0andriy но чему? Непереносимо программировать для переносимой системы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 5 копеек про отладку

т.к. в программе ничего кроме системных вызовов по сути и нет, то для отладки оных удобно использовать утилиту `strace`, по сути в данном случае она сразу выдаст все ошибки:

```
$ strace ./prog02
execve("./prog02", ["./prog02"], 0x7ffd10a5da90 /* 125 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=11513 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
open("test.txt", O_RDWR)                = 3
read(3, NULL, 20)                       = -1 EFAULT (Неправильный адрес)
write(20, NULL, 20)                     = -1 EBADF (Неправильный дескриптор файла)
close(3)                                = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

#### Конкретные ошибки

> ```
> mov ecx, [buffer]
> ```

Здесь в `ecx` помещается **содержимое**, которое находится по адресу `buffer`, а должен помещаться сам адрес буфера. Сравни строчку со своей предыдущей программой.

> ```
> mov ebx, 20
>
> int 0x80 ; "Записали" на экран
> ```

Опечатка; размер должен помещаться в `edx`, а не `ebx`. Кроме того ты выводишь в stdout весь буфер, независимо от того, сколько было прочитано из файла.

> ```
> mov eax, 5
> mov ebx, file
> mov ecx, O_RDWR
> mov edx, 2
> int 0x80
> ```

Т.к. O_CREAT не задан, то значение `edx` задавать не обязательно. Но если задаёшь, то стоит указывать что-то осмысленное, например `0777`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Строку из файла выводит, но не полностью. Осталось вычислить размер буфера, чтобы он выводил весь текст, независимо от того сколько информации будет в файле, но тут уже сам разберусь. Пойду учиться дальше.

Comment: Было бы неплохо упомянуть, что данные знания основываются на вполне конкретной документации, а именно ABI /cc @Konstantin_SH

Comment: @0andriy, ЕМНИП я ему это ему уже упоминал где-то...